# GKE automated pod recycling ideas

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm thinking of a solution to do a rolling update on a schedule without really releasing something. I was thinking of an ENV variable change through kubectl patch to kick off the update in GKE.

The context is we have containers that don't do garbage collection, and the temporary fix and easiest path forward and is cycling out pods frequently that we can schedule on a nightly.

Our naive approach would be to schedule this through our build pipeline, but seems like there's a lot of moving parts.

I haven't looked at Cloud Functions, but I'm sure there's an API that could do this and I'm leaning towards automating this with Cloud Functions.

Or is there already a GKE solution to do this?

Any other approaches to this problem?

I know AWS's ec2 has this feature for ASG, I was looking for the same thing so I don't to do a hacky ENV var change on manifest.

Comment: Just to be sure, you want to change the env var on a schedule, correct?

Comment: It's not clear to me, so you want to do a rolling update just to replace all pods with new ones to fix your issue with garbage collection? Have you already tried with Cloud Build as in [this example](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/automated-deployment)? What about the [Cronjob](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cronjobs) feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two possibilities:

- [Cronjobs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cronjobs). You can use CronJobs to run tasks at a specific time or interval. Suggested for  automatic tasks, such as backups, reporting, sending emails, or cleanup tasks. More details [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/).
- [CI/CD with CloudBuild](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/automated-deployment). When you push a change to your repository, Cloud Build automatically builds and deploys the container to your GKE cluster.